# Proving Volterra operator satisfies $V^*V=K$ for $K=\int_{0}^1 k(y,x)f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I've been trying, unsuccessfully, to prove the following:

> The Volterra operator:
>
> $$ V: L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$$ $$ Vf(t) = \int_{0}^tf(x)dx$$
>
> satisfies $V^*V=K$ for:
>
> $$ V: L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$$ $$K=\int_{0}^1 k(y,x)f(x)dx \quad,\quad k\in C([0,1]^2)$$

I have proven earlier (in case this might help) that $K=ST$ for:

$$S:\big(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_\infty\big)\to \big(L^2, ||\cdot||_{L^2}\big)$$
$$ S(f)=f$$
$$T:\big(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_{L^2}\big)\to \big(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_\infty\big)$$
$$ T(f)=\int_{0}^1 k(y,x)f(x)dx \quad,\quad k\in C([0,1]^2)$$

where $T$ can be expanded to $L^2$.

The only I see of proving the claim, unless I'm missing something, is by computing $V^*V$ and showing that it equals $K$, but I cannot see how to proceed from this point:
$$ \int_y^1\int_0^t f(x)dx dt \stackrel{?}{=}\int_0^1 k(y,x)f(x)dx$$

Clearly, I must be missing something since I'm not yet able to use the fact that $k$ is continuous.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not an exercise in abstract functional analysis. You should compute $V \ast V$ (the composition of $V$ with itself?) and read off what the kernel function $k$ must be. Note that $k \notin C([0,1])$, since it depends on two arguments.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks, I edited the question accordingly. I suppose that's my issue - trying to read off what $k$ must be. How should one approach this? (I'm not sure how to transition to a single integral between $[0,1]$ from the LHS in my last equality).

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920176/self-adjoint-of-volterra-operator