# Help understanding how change of order of integration results in $\int_x^{1} \int_0^{t} f(s)ds dt = \int_{0}^{1} (1- \max(x,t)) f(t) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920176/self-adjoint-of-volterra-operator) question, it mentions that after changing the order of integration, we obtain:

$$\int_x^{1} \int_0^{t} f(s)ds dt = \int_{0}^{1} (1- \max(x,t)) f(t) dt$$

(assume $f\in C[0,1]$ and $x \in [0,1]$).

I am trying to understand why.

**EDIT**

Thanks to dan_fulea and Brian Moehring I identified my mistake and the solution. Below is the correct form:

$$\int_x^{1} \int_0^{t} f(s)ds dt = \int_0^{1} \int_{\max\{x,s\}}^{1} f(s)dt ds = \int_0^{1} f(s)\int_{\max\{x,s\}}^{1} dt ds=\int_0^{1} f(s)\big(1-\max\{x,s\}\big) ds$$

Comment: Hint (I haven't followed up). The original integrand is independent of $t$. The region of integration is a triangle, sliced vertically in one integral and horizontallin the other.

Comment: Why is that letter $y$ so lonely in the whole text? It would be also good to know where does $x$ run in...

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: @dan_fulea Fixed (all the above). Apologies. Mistakenly left my own variables - hence $y$ was lonely... :)

Comment: Wonderful, it is exactly what i wanted! Now why do you change that $f(s)$ into an $f(t)$ - best work in between with some help function $h(s,t)$ instead of $f(s)$...

Comment: @dan_fulea OK - getting close! But I can tell this is not exactly what you meant: $ \int_0^1\int_x^1f(t)\chi_{[s,1]}(t)dtds$. I realise (by reverse engineering) that I need to get $f(t)$ outside of an integral $\int_{\max(x,t)}^1 1ds$ (or similar) to obtain the $(1-\max(...))$ part, but I don't yet see how to separate $f(t)$.

Comment: To reiterate from dan_fulea's point: why have you written $f(t)$ instead of $f(s)$?

Comment: Thanks BrianMoehring and dan_fuela -- I got it now - silly mistake during my change of order of integration. Will fix for the sake of completion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to dan_fulea and Brian Moehring I identified my mistake and the solution:

$$\int_x^{1} \int_0^{t} f(s)ds dt = \int_0^{1} \int_{\max\{x,s\}}^{1} f(s)dt ds = \int_0^{1} f(s)\int_{\max\{x,s\}}^{1}1 dt ds=\int_0^{1} f(s)\big(1-\max\{x,s\}\big) ds$$

Comment: Wonderful, you will never walk alone! I'll put the vote on the solution rather than on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^0$, according to Leibniz's Theorem, $t\mapsto\int_0^tf(s)ds$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$. Thus, an integration by part gives:
$$
\int_x^1\left(\int_0^tf(s)ds\right)dt = \int_0^1f(s)ds - x\int_0^xf(t)dt - \int_x^1f(t)tdt
$$
We notice that $\max(x,t) = x\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t) + t\mathbb{1}_{[x,1]}(t)$. Thus:
$$
= \int_0^1f(t)dt - \int_0^x\max(x,t)f(t)dt - \int_x^1\max(x,t)f(t)dt
$$
With Chasles relation,
$$
= \int_0^1f(t)dt - \int_0^1\max(x,t)f(t)dt = \int_0^1(1-\max(x,t))f(t)dt
$$

As you can see, the key here is the integration by parts, rather than exchanging integrals.